# Measuring Validity and reliability

Tags: reliability, validity

Say you have an independent train ticket system where automatic refunds would be issued in case of a delayed arrival. To determine the arrival time of the train at a certain station you collect data from 100 passengers who are supposed to send in their coordinates and time at which they arrived through an app to a server. Now, some people will lie and some will act honestly. Is there some way to measure the validity and or reliability of all the passengers' responses to find out the statistical truth about when the train actually arrived?